# Is there a way to remove text from path in makefile

Tags: c, linux, makefile, operating-system

I have a makefile and I would like to remove the middle part of the path ['build/cstr/cstr.o'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ztfU.png).
I have tried using `shell find src -name '*.c'` but to no avail and at this point im running out of options. I would appreciate any help. makefile attached

(edit) [folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qA6n1.png)

```
kernel := build/kernel.bin
iso := build/os.iso

linker_script := src/linker.ld
grub_cfg := src/grub.cfg
assembly_source_files := $(wildcard src/*.asm)
assembly_object_files := $(patsubst src/%.asm, \
    build/%.o, $(assembly_source_files))

c_source_files := $(wildcard src/kernel/*.c)
c_object_files := $(patsubst src/kernel/%.c, \
    build/%.o, $(c_source_files))

$(c_object_files): | build
.PHONY: all clean run iso

all: $(kernel)

clean:
    @rm -r build

run: $(iso)
    @qemu-system-x86_64 -cdrom $(iso)

iso: $(iso)

$(iso): $(kernel) $(grub_cfg)
    @mkdir -p build/isofiles/boot/grub
    @cp $(kernel) build/isofiles/boot/kernel.bin
    @cp $(grub_cfg) build/isofiles/boot/grub
    @grub-mkrescue -o $(iso) build/isofiles 2> /dev/null
    @rm -r build/isofiles

$(kernel): $(assembly_object_files) $(c_object_files) $(linker_script)
    
    @echo $(c_object_files)
    @ld -n -T $(linker_script) -o $(kernel) $(assembly_object_files) $(c_object_files)

# compile assembly files
build/%.o: src/%.asm
    @echo $(c_source_files)
    @nasm -felf64 $< -o $@

# compile c files
build/%.o: src/kernel/%.c
    @echo $(c_source_files)
    @gcc -c $< -o $@ -std=c11 -ffreestanding -O2 -Wall -Wextra
    @echo GCC END
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is a little unclear. Do you mean that you want code that will turn `build/cstr/cstr.o` into `build/cstr.o`?

Comment: Please, never show text with images. They are not searchable, not copy-paste-able and much heavier than needed. Moreover they affect accessibility negatively. Please copy-paste the text in your question and [format it properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), instead.

Comment: Why did you try to use `find` (a utility that finds files based on criteria) to modify a string (`build/cstr/cstr.o`)? And why do you show us a Makefile that has nothing to do with your question? May I suggest that you take a look at the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and especially at the [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: if you are getting an error when you build with the makefile, please add the error to your question.

Comment: not seeing a rule that creates the build directory.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.